# ElasticSearch NEST query across multiple types

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, covariance

Given the following POCOs:

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cat
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to perform a query that returns ALL Dogs and only Cats that are Enabled.

The elastic docs provide the following example but not any detail on how to use a Bool with query or filter context to search for specific field values across multiple types:

```
.Search<object>(s => s
    .Size(100)
    .Type(Types.Type(typeof(Dog), typeof(Cat)))                
    .Query(...)
```

How do I perform my query?, Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any way to apply filtering on specific type alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can query on the metadata `_type` field and combine this with queries on other fields. Here's an example. We'll create 100 cats and 100 dogs, setting each even cat to be disabled

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "pets";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, ci => ci
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Dog>(d => d.AutoMap())
            .Map<Cat>(c => c.AutoMap())
        )
    );

    var dogs = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => new Dog
    {
        Name = $"Dog {i}"
    });

    client.IndexMany(dogs);

    var cats = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => new Cat
    {
        Name = $"Cat {i}",
        Enabled = i % 2 == 0 ? false : true
    });

    client.IndexMany(cats);
    client.Refresh(defaultIndex);

    client.Search<object>(s => s
        .Size(100)
        .SearchType(SearchType.Count)
        .Type(Types.Type(typeof(Dog), typeof(Cat)))
        .Query(q => 
            (+q.Term("_type", "cat") && +q.Term("enabled", true)) ||
            +q.Term("_type", "dog")
        )
    );
}
```

The search query takes advantage of operator overloading; the unary `+` operator will mean that the query will be wrapped in a `bool` query `filter` and similarly, `&&` will wrap into a `bool` query `must` (or `filter` in this case as we also use the `+` unary operator to make it a filter), and `||` will wrap into a `bool` query `should`. The resulting executed query looks like

```
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_type": {
                    "value": "cat"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "enabled": {
                    "value": true
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_type": {
                    "value": "dog"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which yields

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 150,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

This is only a count, but if you were to look at the documents, it would be all dogs and only cats that are enabled

Comment: Is there any way to apply filtering on specific type alone?